# What if all resources are placed in one resolution for android app bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

As we all know that Google launch new feature of distributing android apk using android-app-bundle that has so many advantages.

So my question is, how my app will behave if I place all the images/resources in single folder like drawable-xxxhdpi. e.g. Lets say I have one application that uses 5 images. Instead of taking different sizes for different resolutions, I place all the images in single folder (drawable-xxxhdpi) assuming lets android handle it based on device resolution.

As we know that android-app-bundle generates different different apks based on resolutions, languages and so on.

**So in that case what will happen to my app ? How APKs will be generated for different resolutions (Android itself re-scales images and generates bundle ?) What will happen to app, will it crash or working properly for smaller resolution devices ?**

I know this is non- coding question but its technical question. I tried to search for this but not able to find exact answer of it.

I may help to others as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app will work the same as before: Play serves to a given device the files that the Android platform would have loaded if it had served the APK with all the files.

In other words, if an mdpi device would have loaded the resource `res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png`, then that's what Play will serve to that device.

--

Also, slightly unrelated to your question, but note that there are some downsides to providing resources only in xxxhdpi (regardless of whether you publish an APK or an Android AppBundle):

1. The Android platform will have to rescale these images at runtime on lower resolution devices, thus taking some CPU time and making your app slightly slower.
2. Your app is bigger than it could be on lower resolution devices. If you provided also the same resource in `mdpi`, it would obviously be smaller, and that's what Play would serve to an mdpi device, thus making your app smaller for those devices.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. As you are saying that resources are rescaled at runtime, when play is generating apk for mdpi device, how play will generate apk based on different resolution/resource devices like mdpi? Then there will be no any benefit of app bundle as higher resolution image is being included in app bundle as well ?

Comment: Play does not create new files today, so it will serve the xxxhdpi resource (in our example) to all devices. If you want to avoid the rescaling, you need to include the PNG resources for each dpi, then Play will serve the right resource to the right device.

Answer (score 1):

Resource not found exception will be triggered in devices with lower resolutions

Answer (score 0):

Good and very helpful question, I think your application will work fine on xxxhdpi devices but those devices which are mdpi or hdpi will face layout issues. I don't think so there would be any other issue than this.